# Export in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project located on code.google.com, a client TortoiseSVN, the project was exported and imported, and then I pressed the Export and selecting Revision, now when loading any project I have downloaded only the projects with no folder.svn and no icons on the files, What should I do

Answer (score 4):

Use "Check out" to get .svn folders. "Export" only gives you the files, but "Check out" gives you the repository with metadata.